# Why does the UID of /dev/tty1, tty2 change preiodically on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tty, uid

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.

I noticed that the tty which runs the Ubuntu GUI periodically changes from `tty2`, to `tty3`, what is the reason for this?

I also noticed other UID changes, for instance `tty1` has always been the login screen but I recently saw that the UID changed from `root(0)` to `gdm (127)`?

What could explain these UID changes?

Answer (score 0):

Linux organizes its console into virtual consoles which are mapped to devices as `/dev/ttyN` where N is a number.  It is possible to switch between them with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>function key</kbd>, where the function key F1 would switch to /dev/tty1, etc.

When nobody is logged into a virtual console, it is typically owned by root.  GDM generates the login window, and it may take ownership of the virtual console when it does.  (However, I don't see that on my system right now.)  Generally if you select a virtual console with a text login prompt on it, and log in, you will then own that virtual console.

If you are in gnome, in the logout menu, instead of logging out, you can "switch user" which will open a login window on the next available virtual console.  This could cause it to shift to different virtual consoles.

Comment: I was wondering why the GUI which has normally been on tty2 is now on tty3 (hence the UID change) and then changes back to tty2 sometimes. Is there a reason for this switch?

Comment: @Zzgooloo : Because your GUI needs some X-server to run and at launch time, that X-server can be instructed to either keep the tty it is launched from or select another one. The latter seems to be your case.